# Reading several HMTL tables to one EXCEL workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have saved several HTML files with data in table format on GitHub and would now like to read the data to one EXCEL workbook.

As `pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a')` is apparently deprecated, I am now trying to use `openpyxl`.

This is my code:

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# define EXCEL file for output data

book = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\###\\Downloads\\VMA2013_raw-data.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\###\\Downloads\\VMA2013_raw-data.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

# files with WBRA data on Github

filenames= ("WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_52_44.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_54_00.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_55_33.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_59_16.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_07_45.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_08_42.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_10_20.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_15_34.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_16_50.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_17_43.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_18_29.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_19_25.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_20_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_21_46.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_23_01.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_24_06.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_25_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_26_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_27_19.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_28_28.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_28_50.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_30_41.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_31_38.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_32_47.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_33_18.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_00.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_20.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_49.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_35_04.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_36_33.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_37_04.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_37_30.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_38_54.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_39_10.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_40_14.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_40_42.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_41_56.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_42_52.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_44_05.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_45_28.html",
    "WebDataRA-backup-1000.html")
  
# Create URL for each file whose table we want to extract

path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/####/*****/main/VMA2013_tweets/"

for f in filenames:
    url=urljoin(path, f)
    
# Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe
    table = pd.read_html(url)[0] 
    
# Store the dataframe in Excel file

    startrow = writer.sheets['VMA2013'].max_row

    table.to_excel(writer, startrow,index = False)

print("done")
```

The error notification I am getting is:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3488\720253268.py in <module>
      6 # define EXCEL file for output data
      7 
----> 8 book = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\###\\Downloads\\VMA2013_raw-data.xlsx")
      9 writer = pandas.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\###\\Downloads\\VMA2013_raw-data.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
     10 writer.book = book

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    314     """
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
--> 316                         data_only, keep_links)
    317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in __init__(self, fn, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    122     def __init__(self,  fn, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
    123                   data_only=False, keep_links=True):
--> 124         self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
    125         self.valid_files = self.archive.namelist()
    126         self.read_only = read_only

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in _validate_archive(filename)
     94             raise InvalidFileException(msg)
     95 
---> 96     archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
     97     return archive
     98 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1256         try:
   1257             if mode == 'r':
-> 1258                 self._RealGetContents()
   1259             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1260                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1323             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1324         if not endrec:
-> 1325             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1326         if self.debug > 1:
   1327             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I cannot make sense of it. Why is a zip file required? The EXCEL workbook has been created in my Downloads folder as assigned, but when I try and open it, the file is broken.

When I create the required file beforehand, the error notification is this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3488\1843287704.py in <module>
     70     startrow = writer.sheets['VMA2013'].max_row
     71 
---> 72     table.to_excel(writer, startrow,index = False)
     73 
     74 print("done")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2289             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
   2290             engine=engine,
-> 2291             storage_options=storage_options,
   2292         )
   2293 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    843                 startrow=startrow,
    844                 startcol=startcol,
--> 845                 freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
    846             )
    847         finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
    447         else:
    448             wks = self.book.create_sheet()
--> 449             wks.title = sheet_name
    450             self.sheets[sheet_name] = wks
    451 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\child.py in title(self, value)
     88                     raise ValueError("Worksheet titles must be str")
     89 
---> 90         m = INVALID_TITLE_REGEX.search(value)
     91         if m:
     92             msg = "Invalid character {0} found in sheet title".format(m.group(0))

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could not get `openpyxl` to work, I am now writing my HTML data to separate EXCEL files which I am merging afterwards:

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# define EXCEL file for output data

outpath = "C:\\Users\\###\\Downloads\\"

# files with WBRA data on Github

filenames= ("WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_52_44.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_54_00.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_55_33.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T11_59_16.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_07_45.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_08_42.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_10_20.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_15_34.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_16_50.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_17_43.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_18_29.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_19_25.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_20_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_21_46.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_23_01.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_24_06.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_25_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_26_53.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_27_19.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_28_28.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_28_50.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_30_41.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_31_38.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_32_47.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_33_18.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_00.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_20.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_34_49.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_35_04.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_36_33.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_37_04.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_37_30.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_38_54.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_39_10.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_40_14.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_40_42.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_41_56.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_42_52.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_44_05.html",
    "WebDataRA-2022-09-21T12_45_28.html",
    "WebDataRA-backup-1000.html")
  
# Create webpage URL for each file whose table we want to extract

path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/###/***/main/VMA2013_tweets/"

counter=0
for f in filenames:
    url=urljoin(path, f)
    print(url)
    counter+= 1
    
# Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe
    table = pd.read_html(url)[0] 
    
    outfile=os.path.join(outpath, str(counter) + ".xlsx")
    print(outfile)
    
# Store the dataframe in NEW Excel file
    
    table.to_excel(outfile)
    

print("done")
```